# Applying Riesz Representation Theorem to prove $g \in L^{p}(E) = 0$ if integral of $fg$ is 0 for all $f$ in dense subset of $L^{q}(E)$

Tags: integration, lp-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I know this question [has been asked before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2759115/integral-of-function-in-lpe-times-functions-in-dense-set-being-0-implies), but I wanted to try a different proof and get help tying up a piece of the proof that wasn't clear to me in that answer for $p < \infty$ (basically it seemed like the reasoning of that OP only showed $\int_{E} fg \leq 0$ where we need it to be equal to 0). The problem as it was given to me expects me to apply the Riesz Representation Theorem, so here is my attempt:

Let $E$ be measurable, $1 \leq p < \infty$, $q$ the conjugate of $p$, and $S$ dense in $L^{q}(E)$. We want to show that if $g \in L^{p}(E)$ and $\int_{E} fg = 0$ for all $f \in S$, then $g = 0$.

Now, by Riesz Rep, we know that in particular for the Id operator, there exists unique $f \in L^{q}(E)$ such that $Id(g) = g = \int_{E} gf$ for all $g \in L^{p}(E)$.

Since $S$ is dense in $L^{q}(E)$, there exists a sequence $\{s_{n}\} \in S$ such that the limit as n goes to $\infty$ of $||f- s_{n}||_{q}$ is 0. Thus:

$g = Id(g) = \int_{E} gf = \int_{E} g[f - s_{n} + s_{n}] = \int_{E}g[f - s_{n}] + \int_{E} gs_{n} \leq ||g||_{p}||f - s_{n}||_{q}$, which goes to 0.

My hangup: All this proves is that $g \leq 0$. How do we prove $g \geq 0$?

Comment: I'm confused. $\int_E fg$ is a number, but $g$ is a function. What does it mean for $g = \int_E fg$? This holds only if $g$ is constant, but that isn't at all what you need to prove.

Comment: Just consider $|Id(g)|$ instead of $Id(g)$ and apply the triangle inequality when needed. You will then get $|Id(g)|\leq 0$.

Comment: Theoretical Economist, I think you're right and now I'm also confused, but what WOULD it look like to apply RRT to the Id operator?

Comment: Lorenzo Quarisa, so I was on the right track with the Id operator after all despite TE's comment? But regardless, I now see your idea fills in the missing piece of that other proof, since if I can prove absolute value of the integral is 0, I know the integral is 0, and then I can apply the other lemma.